# How is fuel pressure maintained when the pump isn't running?

Tags: fuel-system, theory

Pretty simple question, if liquids are incompressible then how is fuel pressure "stored" when the fuel pump isn't running, i.e. after turning to run and waiting a few seconds, but not turning to start?

Edit: To clarify, I'm asking more what part of the system is compressed to provide the constant pressure, is it in fact the fuel, the lines expanding, something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the use of one way or non-return valves. Which is why most fuel systems have warnings about which components / pipes should be disconnected or not or the order when working on them - some are at very high pressure.

Also note that liquids are compressible, but as it needs a lot of pressure for a small volume change, us engineers assume incompressible as it simplifies some of the maths. Some systems have a pressure chamber or use the flexibilty in the pipes - it all depends on what parameters need to be covered.

Comment: I guess what I was asking more is what part of the system is actually compressed to hold the pressure? Is it the small amount of compressing that the fuel _is_ capable of, or the lines expanding, something else?

Comment: Ok , first thing liquids are compressible, but as it needs a lot of pressure for a small volume change, us engineers assume incompressible as it simplifies some of the maths. Some systems have a pressure chamber or use the flexibilty in the pipes - it all depends on what parameters need to be covered.